# Error code 81011 - Failed to send message - Was working fine earlier today, now whole system is broken

Tags: twilio, sms

Been working on Chatgpt responses and prompts for my studio flow and testing everything works, everything had been working fine with sms responses, however I started to notice the trigger start to get slower to response to incoming messages, taking a couple of messages before it would trigger and now it doesn't trigger at all.

Upon looking at the error logs I'm getting 81011 - Failed to send message
[image]

Upon looking directly at the documentation it states the following:

Studio was unable to send a Message. This is usually due to incorrect setup of a Message Widget.

Possible causes:

- You have an invalid number. - Not too sure what it means by this.
- You are missing a message body - Message body is full of text, so its not that.
- You are missing a Media URL - Didn't have media URL to begin with and been working fine, so I don't think its that either.

thanks to the logs I know its definitely receiving my incoming message and its trying to activate the widget just it isn't, so some help would be greatly appreciated on how I can solve this.

Also I noticed about the A2P Compliance when using Twilio numbers, as I currently use SMS routing via the US for my UK stuff, is this something I need to sign up for, and is it possible for this to be also causing some of my problems?